# How to make preloader using React with Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I have such problem: I made preloader for my React App, and when the user click on button `LoginIn` (before this enter his email and passwords) the loader starting to work, but when the user entered wrong email or password, or something happend wrong with server side, it has to show error to user, but in this step it shows preloader which doesn't dissappear and it's logically,because it sests `loadingAuth === true`, and when `loadingAuth === true` it shows preloader, but because of error it cant't set `false`. So, what in this situation I need to do?

---

**Thunk:**

```
export const loginInWithEmail = (email, password) => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(loadingAuth(true)) //start preloader
    fire.auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(() => dispatch(loadingAuth(false))) //end preloader
        .catch((error) => {
            dispatch(getError(error));
        });
};
```

---

**Component:**

```
const MyComponent = ({//props}) => {
  return(
    <div>
      {isLoading === true  
        ? <AuthPreloader /> 
        : <Component/>
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already call `dispatch(getError(error))` when an error occurs. Let's say the initial error state value is `null` and the error state is mapped to a prop called `error`.

You can then use your error prop like you did with `isLoading` like this:

```
const MyComponent = ({//props}) => {
  // ...
  let content;

  if (error) {
    content = <p>There is an error</p>;
  } else if (isLoading) {
    content = <AuthPreloader />;
  } else {
    content = <Component />;
  }

  return(<div>{content}</div>)
}
```